# Wordpress plugins add parent menu option in admin main right

Tags: admin-menu

I need to add a menu item but it is available as a parent item, I am trying it as follows but in the menu option it is shown as the child of the parent item Settings> My plugins name:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin' );

function my_plugin() {
    add_options_page( 
        'My Options',
        'My plugins name',
        'my_plugin',
        'my-plugin.php',
        'my_plugin_page'
    );
}
```

I have reviewed this section: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities, but there are many options, I am learning to create plugins for Wordpress.

*Thank you very much for your help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's a helper function for adding pages to the settings section, not the lower level API you expected:

> This function is a simple wrapper for a call to `add_submenu_page()`, passing the received arguments and specifying `options-general.php` as the `$parent_slug` argument. This means the new options page will be added as a sub menu to the Settings menu.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page

Instead, you want `add_menu_page` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

Comment: Many thanks to this option I can add submenu, depending on the parent menu?

Comment: yeah, `add_submenu_page`, look at the related functions on the docs